# Typescript type extends any given type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build a custom table in Angular, and I wanted to create a `TableItem` type that ensure that every type you insert into the table, it has a `label` property.

Here there is an example of usage:

```
    <app-my-table [items]="items"></app-my-table>
```

For example here items could be any object but must have the `label` property.
I can't find a proper strategy to do it.

Comment: What did you try so far? You should be able to simply have `@Input() items: TableItem[]` in the component.

Comment: Need more detail than this, sham has given a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an indexer for this e.g.

```
interface TableItem {
    label: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}

items: TableItem[] = [
  { label: 'A', otherField: 1 }, // All good
  { otherField: 2 } // Property 'label' is missing in type ...
]
```

Comment: Why is an indexer needed?

Comment: I assumed they are asking "I want a type that can match any type as long as it has a label property" and an indexer is a good way of achieving this.

Comment: I mean...no, it's not. Types in TS have to be structurally compatible to be assignable. Thus `interface TableItem { label: string; }` [already accepts types that have other properties](https://tsplay.dev/NlDzGN). Why exactly is an indexer needed?

Comment: If you want to assign an object literal maybe? I don't have the use case they're asking for,  but presumably they're encountering some sort of issue with assignment which is why they asked this question.

Comment: That was indeed what I was asking, thank you!!